# How to use filter_at over a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I want to apply a filter_at over a list of dataframes. I can apply it to a single dataframe within this list like so:

```
    dat_list[[1]] <- dat_list[[1]] %>% filter_at(vars(c("test", "x")), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Here is the test dataset:

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, test = 4:6, x = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat2 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, test = 4:6, x = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat3 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, test = 4:6, x = 7:9), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat1[1,2] <- NA
dat1[1,3] <- NA
dat1[3,2] <- NA
dat1[3,3] <- NA

dat3[1,2] <- NA
dat3[1,3] <- NA
dat3[3,2] <- NA
dat3[3,3] <- NA

dat_list <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
```

Comment: Do you only have those 2 column + the id? If so you can just do `lapply(dat_list, na.omit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat_list2 <- map(dat_list, ~filter_at(., vars(c("test", "x")), all_vars(!is.na(.))))

dat_list2
#> [[1]]
#>   id test x
#> 1  2    5 8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   id test x
#> 1  1    4 7
#> 2  2    5 8
#> 3  3    6 9
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   id test x
#> 1  2    5 8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0, we can use `filter` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)#1.0.0
library(purrr)
dat_list %>%
      map(~ .x %>% filter(across(c(test, x), ~ !is.na(.x))))
#[[1]]
#  id test x
#1  2    5 8

#[[2]]
#  id test x
#1  1    4 7
#2  2    5 8
#3  3    6 9

#[[3]]
#  id test x
#1  2    5 8
```